# (android)How can I read word in my txt file on android?

Tags: java, android

I mean that , I write 100 words(every each line contains one word so I write 100 line to 100 word) in a.txt. And I want to acces this txt in my application on android. And for example I only want to 6.word .For this I want to write a function.

```
public String generate(int a)
{
//I want to return a. word in my txt

//
//
//
//
return ...
}
```

And I don't know how I do this?

Comment: Just explode the string into an array using a space as the delimiter and access the `a`'th element.

Comment: How can move the txt file to phone ? Must I use databaase?

Comment: Or in code I must use string array ?

Comment: You stated that you have a text file. Just open the text file in your code. Look up how to do file IO on Android.

Comment: How can I open ? Where do move my txt file? on root folder?

Comment: Are you trying to access a file on the SD Card?

Comment: I want to move my txt file to x place;

x place : which I reach there in code  dinamic. every phone can access

Comment: no actually.How can I replace the my txt to the sd card ? I have but I dont know How I replace? Where do I move it ? on res folder or what folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the txt in the `res/raw` folder.
Let's say the file is named **ff.txt**.

Then just open the file as an input stream using the `openRawResource()` method and providing the resource id as input (e.g.: package.name.here.**R.raw.ff**).

Once you have the `InputStream` returned by the `openRawResource()` method you can do everything you need with the file as you would normally do in a generic java application.

Comment: last  question :
if I want to 54. line of my txt How I do This

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your last comment, but, please, take a look at the documentation on InputStream here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html. Also a very simple example is shown here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstream.html